# Grab Keys from JSON Array Without Repeating

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, elasticsearch

Consider the following JSON array returned from a request sent to an Elasticsearch cluster:

```
[
    {
        "_type": "Event example",
        "_source": {
            "democarrier_s": "vodafone UK",
            "m-Ecosystem_s": "iOS",
            "demo-application": "demo",
            "demo-country-code": "GB"
        }
    },
    {
        "_type": "Event example",
        "_source": {
            "democarrier_s": "Verizon",
            "m-Ecosystem_s": "iOS",
            "demo-application": "demo1",
            "demo-country-code": "US"
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to figure out how to grab all of the unique keys from this document without repeating and without hard-coding any of the values and store them into an object of the following form:

```
columns = ['_type', '_source.democarrier_s', '_source.m-Ecosystem_s', '_source.demo-application', '_source.demo-country-code'];
```

Could someone help me figure out how to achieve this? I've been trying to loop through the document and store the keys but I can't quite figure it out. '_type' can be hard coded into the columns object because it will always exist.

Thank you in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just 2 levels you could do this:

```js
var data = [
    {
        "_type": "Event example",
        "_source": {
            "democarrier_s": "vodafone UK",
            "m-Ecosystem_s": "iOS",
            "demo-application": "demo",
            "demo-country-code": "GB"
        }
    },
    {
        "_type": "Event example",
        "_source": {
            "democarrier_s": "Verizon",
            "m-Ecosystem_s": "iOS",
            "demo-application": "demo1",
            "demo-country-code": "US"
        }
    }
]

var keys = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {

  for (var key in item) {
    var hasProperties = false;
    
    if (typeof item[key] !== 'string') {
      
      for (var key2 in item[key]) {
        hasProperties = true;
        
        var keyName = key + "." + key2;

        if (keys.indexOf(keyName) < 0)
            keys.push(keyName);
      }
    }
    
    if (!hasProperties && keys.indexOf(key) < 0) {
       keys.push(key);
    }
 }
});

keys.forEach(function (k) { console.log(k) });
```